# Rest API to get Torrent info based on torrent Hash

Tags: python, rest, torrent

I need to get details of a TV show episode or a Movie based on a torrent info hash. Is there any REST API for the same? If not which website is the best to scrape such details?

e.g. - Input - d532d9e1eb44933f3989b8447101cd5eeff16d6f
       output - Better Call Saul Season 1 Episode 1

P.s. - As long as it is REST, it doesn't matter but still "I m trying to implement this using python."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTDigg.org has a Search API (by request), see: http://btdigg.org/about/
I don't know if it is REST.

Otherwise it's not hard to request like:
http://btdigg.org/search?info_hash=7a1073bc39e6b0b01e3730227b8ffea6aeac5d59
and get the name from the result.
(Name: ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso)